# Java: After adding 2 identical objects to a Set, it contains the 2 elements

Tags: java, set, equals, hashcode

After adding two identical objects to a Set, I would expect the set to contain only one element.

```
public void addIdenticalObjectsToSet(){
    Set<Foo> set = new HashSet<Foo>();
    set.add(new Foo("totoro"));
    set.add(new Foo("totoro"));
    Assert.assertEquals(1, set.size());            // PROBLEM: SIZE=2
}

private class Foo {
    private String id;
    public Foo(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj!= null && obj instanceof Foo &&
            ((Foo)obj).getId().equals(this.getId());
    }
    public int hashcode() {
        return this.getId().hashCode();
    }
}
```

I consider two objects as identical if they have the same id (String).

Other strange thing: Neither Foo.equals nor Foo.hashcode are accessed, as far as I can tell using debug/breakpoints. What am I missing?

Comment: try to use @Override anotation

Comment: Try applying @Override on the methods which you think are overridden

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
public int hashcode() {
        return this.getId().hashCode();
    }
```

should be

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
        return this.getId().hashCode();
    }
```

The annotation would have told you about the spelling mistake.

There should also be a (missing) little triangle symbol in your IDE on the method to indicate if an interface is being implemented or a parent method overridden.

Comment: +1: Similar to using `compareto` instead of `compareTo`.  There is a `hashcode` method in the Java 6 JDK ;)

Comment: I think FindBugs would also have caught this. Something about implementing `equals` but not `hashCode`.